# MS SQL Excel Query wildcards

Tags: sql-server, excel, wildcard, sql-like

I'm trying to introduce `LIKE` clause with wildcards in SQL query that runs within Excel 2007, where parameters are taken from specific Excel cells:

```
SELECT Elen_SalesData_View.ItemCode, Elen_SalesData_View.ItemDescription, 
Elen_SalesData_View.ItemValue, Elen_SalesData_View.Quantity, 
Elen_SalesData_View.CustomerId, Elen_SalesData_View.CustomerName, 
Elen_SalesData_View.SalesInvoiceId, Elen_SalesData_View.EffectiveDate, 
Elen_SalesData_View.CountryId
FROM SM_Live.dbo.Elen_SalesData_View Elen_SalesData_View
WHERE (Elen_SalesData_View.EffectiveDate>=? And Elen_SalesData_View.EffectiveDate<=?) 
AND (Elen_SalesData_View.CustomerName<>'PROMO') 
AND (Elen_SalesData_View.ItemDescription LIKE '%'+?+'%')
```

The `EffectiveDate` parameters are running fine and bringing back data as expected. But since I introduced `LIKE` - query runs, but returns nothing.

It doesn't return any results without wildcards either (full description entered):

```
(Elen_SalesData_View.ItemDescription LIKE ?)
```

Is there a restriction to wildcards or LIKE clause? If so, is there a way around it? (I cannot use `CONTAINS`, as the `ItemDescription` field is not `FULLTEXT`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query was correct. There was something wrong with the actual spreadsheet. After redoing all from scratch - it worked!

```
SELECT Elen_SalesData_View.ItemCode, Elen_SalesData_View.ItemDescription, 
Elen_SalesData_View.ItemValue, Elen_SalesData_View.Quantity, 
Elen_SalesData_View.CustomerId, Elen_SalesData_View.CustomerName, 
Elen_SalesData_View.SalesInvoiceId, Elen_SalesData_View.EffectiveDate, 
Elen_SalesData_View.CountryId
FROM SM_Live.dbo.Elen_SalesData_View Elen_SalesData_View
WHERE (Elen_SalesData_View.ItemDescription Like '%'+?+'%') 
AND (Elen_SalesData_View.EffectiveDate>=?) AND (Elen_SalesData_View.EffectiveDate<=?)
AND (Elen_SalesData_View.CustomerName<>'PROMO')
```

Comment: Excel automatically assigns parameter types when you create a query (integer, date, string etc.). You can view or change parameter type using VBA. When you modify existing query - especially add/change parameter order - you may experience problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) which suggests that % itself is the wildcard character, although it may depend on the dialect of SQL you are using.  If this is the case then your `LIKE` clause will simply be `LIKE '%'` but untested.

Comment: % is a wildcard as per my post. It means 'anything'. My query works in SQL query directly as expected, but not in Excel query

Answer (score 0):

I've just got this to work by using the `(Elen_SalesData_View.ItemDescription LIKE ?)` syntax then having the cell that contains the parameter value include the wildcard characters. If you don't/can't include the wildcards then create a formula in a separate cell to wrap the value in % characters and use this cell for the parameter value.

Rhys